# Classes and Objects with ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, arraylist

I am trying to  create a program that takes a file name as a parameter, opens that file, reads in all of the text in that file (about 1 paragraph) and then give the user a few options to manipulate the paragraph.

I am having trouble with the scanner which asks the user for the command. For example, if the user presses 1, I want it to take the user to public void palindrome (), but it won't compile.

I haven't written in the code yet for public void palindrome, but there shouldn't be any compiling errors.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;


public class Test {

        public static void main (String [] args) {

                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
                ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
                while( scanner.hasNext() ) {
                        strings.add( scanner.next() );
                }

                ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>(strings);



                while (true) {
                        System.out.println ("\nWhat would you like to do? Here are your options: \nPress 1 to Print all palindromes \nPress 2 to Replace any letter  \nPress 3 to remove all occurences of a word \nPress 4 to exit\n");
                        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                        String command = s.next();

                        if (command.equals("1")) {
                                a.palindrome();
                        } else if (command.equals("2")){
                                a.letter();
                        } else if (command.equals("3")){
                                a.word();
                        }  else if (command.equals("4")){
                                System.exit(0);
                        }
                }
        }

        public void palindrome () {

        }


        public void letter () {

        }

        public void word () {

        }

}
```

Comment: The compiler gives an error when it fails to compile. Why don't you post the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is Create an instance of your `Test` class

```
Test test = new Test();
```

Then call

```
test.palindrome();
```

Compiler fails because, since you called `a.palindrome()` and `a` being an instance of `ArrayList<String>()`, and it doesn't have a method `ArrayList` class doesn't have a method called `palindrome()`

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `a` as an `Arraylist`. and are calling `a.palindrome()`.

An `Arraylist` does not have  the method `palindrome()`, I believe you just want to call `palindrome()` of your `Test` class.

To do this either:

- Create an instance of `Test` within your main class then call `palindrome()` on that instance (preferred option)

  or
- make the method static then call `Test.palindrome()`

In either case you may want to consider having it take in argument of an `Arraylist`